# SQL Server recursive query with associated table

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a typical parent/child relationship table to represent folders.  My challenge is using it in conjunction with another table.

The `folder` table is like this:

```
+--+----+--------+
|id|name|parentid|
+--+----+--------+
|1 |a   |null    |
+--+----+--------+
|2 |b   |1       |
+--+----+--------+
|3 |c1  |2       |
+--+----+--------+
|4 |c2  |2       |
+--+----+--------+
```

The `association` table is like this:

```
+--+--------+
|id|folderid|
+--+--------+
|66|2       |
+--+--------+
|77|3       |
+--+--------+
```

so that where `association.id = 66` has a relationship to `folder.id = 2`

**What I need to do is find the `association.id` of the first ancestor with a record in the `association` table.**.  Using the example data above, given `folder.id` of `3` I expect to find `77`; given `folder.id` of `2` or `4` I expect to find `66`; any other `folder.id` value would find null.

Finding folder ancestry can be done with a common table expression like this:

```
WITH [recurse] (id,name,parentid,lvl) AS
(
    select a.id,a.name,a.parentid,0 FROM folder AS a   
    WHERE a.id='4'
    UNION ALL
    select r.id,r.name,r.parentid,lvl+1 FROM folder as r 
    INNER JOIN [recurse] ON recurse.parentid = r.id
)
SELECT * from [recurse] ORDER BY lvl DESC
```

yielding the results:

```
+--+----+--------+---+
|id|name|parentid|lvl|
+--+----+--------+---+
|1 |a   |        |2  |
+--+----+--------+---+
|2 |b   |1       |1  |
+--+----+--------+---+
|4 |c2  |2       |0  |
+--+----+--------+---+
```

To include the `association.id` I've tried using a `LEFT JOIN` in the recursive portion of the CTE, but this is not allowed by SQL Server.

What workaround do I have for this?

Or better yet, is the a way to query directly for the particular `association.id`? (e.g., without walking through the results of the CTE query that I have been attempting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, r.parentid, r.lvl, a.folderid, a.id as associationid 
FROM [recurse] r
LEFT JOIN [association] a 
ON r.id = a.folderid
WHERE a.folderId IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY lvl DESC
```

This will give you the records that have values in the association table.  Then you could limit it to the first record that has a value or just grab the top result

Comment: thanks!  I was stuck thinking about how to use the recursion statement and didn't think about using the result.